# How to list data from Parse.com on a webpage using cURL

Tags: json, parsing, curl, get

I am trying to get a JSON array with data from my Parse.com account. I looked at using the REST API but I don't understand how to implement this on a web page. Do I have to use PHP? Or Javascript?

I've been using the Parse.com [support page](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries) to help me.

I need this page to show all my data stored on Parse so that I can then call it from the Google Maps API to overlay points on a map.

> curl -X GET \
>
> -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myid" \
>
> -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: myrestid" \
>
> https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore/

Comment: You could do this with either. Search for sending headers in HTTP requests in whatever you decide to use. I would wager Parse has a library for JavasScript.